# Network Access Points providing cert on connection, how?

Tags: ssl, wireless-access-point, ssl-certificate, tls

How is it connection providers in public locations are able to send a certificate on connection?

I seem to recall there is a protocol they use, but I read that many years ago.

Or is it as simple as on receipt of a handshake request without their certificate they just send it back to the device to install?

I’ve been trying to find out online but all search results come back with info on creating or manual install.

Apologies if it seems obvious or redundant. I’ve seen it when connecting to Wi-Fi on a ferry or in a shop (and I don’t install, I’d rather look out of the window than be MITM’d).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about. In the context of wireless access points there is [EAP-TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP_Transport_Layer_Security_(EAP-TLS)) - but the certificate used there is about authentication of the access point to the client and not about MITM.

Comment: When I join a network I receive a prompt to install a certificate. There is no additional communication regarding the purpose of this certificate. 
But I’m interested in the mechanism/protocol the AP used to issue it.

Comment: It's likely EAP-TLS then. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/122846/if-i-accept-a-certificate-in-order-to-use-my-company-s-wi-fi-am-i-vulnerable-to